# Building a 3D and 2D map with RealSense and RTABMAP

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, realsense, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I am very new to Ros platform. I'm trying to build a 3d and 2d map with RealSense r200.  As far as i know the rtabmap doesn't have a standalone driver for RealSense r200. I tried several things but couldn't managed to make it work.

Could you please explain the steps and provide the commands that can help me to reach my goal?(also maybe launch files)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240378/building-a-3d-and-2d-map-with-realsense-and-rtabmap/) by [dumbled0ge](https://answers.ros.org/users/27571/dumbled0ge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
$ roslaunch realsense_camera r200_nodelet_rgbd.launch
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch depth_topic:=/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dumbled0ge](https://answers.ros.org/users/27571/dumbled0ge/) on 2016-08-01**:
When I tried this commands, I get an error like this:

[camera/camera_nodelet_manager - 2] process has died [pid 22596, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager

...

**Comment by [dumbled0ge](https://answers.ros.org/users/27571/dumbled0ge/) on 2016-08-01**:
I've managed to run it with these command set btw:

- roslaunch realsense realsense_r200_launch.launch
- rosrun resize_image resize_image -i /camera/depth/image_raw -o /camera/depth/image_resized --aw 640 --ah 480
- roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch ... ( subscribed topics )

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-08-01**:
well, make sure that `/camera/depth/image_raw` is registered with the RGB image.